# Using categories instead of WoE values

Tags: logistic, classification, categorical-data, data-transformation, credit-scoring

As for as I can understand, the Weight of Evidence strategy is the following:

For continuous independent variables : First, create bins (categories / groups) for a continuous independent variable and then combine categories with similar WOE values and replace categories with WOE values. Use WOE values rather than input values in your model.

It was used in an [excellent example](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/225209_df0130c5a0614790b6365676b9372c07.html#2data_analysis_and_variable_creation) of credit scoring

What I do not understand is the following: the author in the link above found a proper grouping of variables (both continuous and categorical) and then he treated all the variables as factors without assigning the WoE values. Is this equivalent to the strategy described above?